# Stub NuxtLink in Storybook

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, storybook

I currently have a component which uses `NuxtLink`. When I try to render it in Storybook it states that it cannot find the `NuxtLink` component. I am trying to stub the component so the story will render correctly. This still seems to give the same error.

What would be the correct way to stub the `NuxtLink` component?

```
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/vue3'
import { Header } from './../src/components'
import { RouterLinkStub } from '@vue/test-utils'

const meta: Meta<typeof HeaderMobile> = {
  title: 'Header',
  component: Header,
  render: (args: any) => ({
    components: {
      Header,
      NuxtLink: RouterLinkStub
    },
    setup() {
      return { args }
    },
    template: '<Header v-bind="args" />'
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can globally stub the `NuxtLink` component by replacing it with a regular anchor tag. On click, the link is not called, but the target is logged to the "Actions" tab of Storybook.

**Solution for Storybook 7**

Add to `preview.ts`:

```typescript
import { setup } from "@storybook/vue3";
import { action } from "@storybook/addon-actions";

setup((app) => {
  app.component("NuxtLink", {
    props: {
      to: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
    methods: {
      log() {
        action("link target")(this.to);
      },
    },
    template: '<a @click="log"><slot></slot></a>',
  });
});
```

**Solution for Storybook 6**

Add to `preview.js`:

```typescript
import { app } from "@storybook/vue3";
import { action } from "@storybook/addon-actions";

app.component("NuxtLink", {
  props: ["to"],
  methods: {
    log() {
      action("link target")(this.to);
    },
  },
  template: '<a @click="log"><slot></slot></a>',
});
```